# WPF databinding to display number in an appropriate currency

Tags: wpf, data-binding, format, currency

I need to display a value in a currency format (EUR / USD / YEN etc.) depending on the currency value stored in the database.

In the database the data is stored like:

```
Id    Value   Currency
1     1000    EUR
2     1500    USD
3     9650    USD
```

In XAML, **I'd like to know how I can show the value in a correct currency format**. 
For example, if I read the first line from the database (Id=1), I like to show it on UI as €1,000 but if I read the second line (Id=2) it should be shown as $1,500.

Right now my XAML MVVM binding looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem, StringFormat=c0}" ...
```

...and for me this displays the value always as $1,500 which I do not want.

Comment: Why not have a string as a property which returns SelectedItem formatted how you want it, and just bind to it? I always find putting logic like this in your view problematic and difficult to test.

Answer (score 4):

A converter class can do the trick for you to achieve the desired behavior

```
public class CurrencyConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return GetCurrency(values);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    private string GetCurrency(object[] values)
    {
        switch (values[1].ToString())
        {
            case "USD":
                return string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", values[0]);

            case "EUR":
                return string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}", values[0]);

            default:
                return string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Simply use the converter in XAML with your `TextBlock` bindings.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{local:CurrencyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Value"/>
            <Binding Path="Currency"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: +1 for a great converter and the accompanying walk-through.  Make it inherit from MarkupExtension to provide the coup de grace

Comment: @GarryVass: Thank you for the useful suggestion. Updated the answer and it looks better now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The string format you're using is based on current system locale so it's not a way to go at all. In your situation you would be interested in something like such a converter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx

Pass in two values (currency and amount), return back a string representation to be shown on UI.